# Changing the startup page

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, c#-4.0

I am creating an application that stores setting selections made by the user.  Some of those selections are designed to control which form in the application opens at program start.

I have been looking for a way to accomplish this and have not found a way that works.  I have found many ways to change the "permanent" startup form but not a way to change the default form within the application.
I am even willing to control this by using command line arguments to start, such as...

tce.exe /profile versus tce.exe /custom

Thank you for ideas on how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adjust this in the `Program.cs` class within the static void method named `Main`. Example:

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // custom logic here to determine which form to show
        if (Settings.Default.IsAdmin)
        {
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
        else
        {
            Application.Run(new Form2());
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure the *Startup Object* is set to the `Program` class in your project properties.

[image]

Comment: Perfect solution!  Thank you.